# How to fix Apache error on Catalina : 403 Forbidden / Client denied by server configuration

Tags: macos, apache, macos-catalina

I've been stuck on this issue for 3 days now. I can access the www folder, but when i try to access a subfolder , i get the 403 Forbidden. Checking the Apache error log , i got this  :

> [Wed Oct 23 13:04:42.597752 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 60180]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:56676] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /users/admin/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www/soft/public_html/, referer:
>   http://127.0.0.1/

Here is how it's configured on httpd.conf :

```
DocumentRoot "/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www"
<Directory "/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +Indexes
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have several other subfolders inside www that i can access, only the 'soft' folder get me the error.

Please help !